# Primary Key error when trying to create Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Running into a problem creating a Foreign Key after creating a Parent/Child table scheme with partitioning setup.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MessageHeader]
   ([MessageHeaderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MessageHeaderGlobalId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [CreatedDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL
   )
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MessageHeader]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PC_MessageHeader_CreatedDateTime_1] 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MessageHeaderID], [CreatedDateTime] ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = OFF) 
ON [PS_Monthly] ([CreatedDatetime])

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MessageDataInfo]
    ([MessageDataInfoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [MessageHeaderID] [int] NOT NULL,
     [CreatedDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MessageDataInfo] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [PC__CreatedDateTime_1] 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MessageDataInfoID], [CreatedDateTime])
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = OFF) 
    ON [PS_Monthly] ([CreatedDatetime])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MessageDataInfo]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_HeaderID] 
    FOREIGN KEY([MessageHeaderID]) 
    REFERENCES [dbo].[MessageHeader] ([MessageHeaderID])
```

What happens is I get the error:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.MessageHeader' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_HeaderID'.

I am not sure why this is happening because that column is obviously the primary key! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I get an error on the first `ALTER` Statement: "Column name 'MessageHeaderID' does not exist in the target table or view."  Should that say `MessageReceivedHeaderID`?

Comment: Ahhh yes, sorry was trying to shorten names to make it more readable.  Edited.

Comment: I would suggest you to have an additional ID column in your Primary key table and then reference that in you foreign key.

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing (see Polly's comment below) with CreatedDateTime.

Comment: What I mean is you can have a surrogate key in your Parent table and it should be unique, and then you can reference it as foreign key in you child table.

Comment: If your primary key is a composite of two columns, then **ALL** foreign keys referencing it **must include BOTH columns**, too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to create a foreign key only on part of Primary key of the parent table. You have to use whole primary key to create a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreign key is referencing a single column, but the primary key on MessageHeader is composite. You probably don't mean it to be, so remove CreatedDateTime from the statement that creates the primary key (the first ALTER TABLE one.)